# Access to MySQL float values

Tags: mysql, ms-access, odbc, export, mariadb

I'm trying to migrate multiple MS Access databases into one single MariaDB. 
Using ODBC, i've set up a macro that looks like

```
Do Until rs.EOF
    'export tables names to lower case
    DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "ODBC Database" _
     , "ODBC;DSN=R2D2Test;" _
     , acTable, rs("Name"), LCase(rs("Name"))
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Macro seems to be working fine, but whenever it tries to export a table containing Double Float values, I get this error :

```
Incorrect column specifier for column doubleField 1063
```

Now i've set up my DB to put out logs of what queries came last :

```
Query CREATE TABLE `myTable`(`varField` VARCHAR(255),`doubleField` FLOAT(255), ...
```

I know that you're not supposed to write "Float(255)" in a MySQL environment , but this is the way that an ODBC export is setup. And exporting manually every single table I have to would simply take way too much time.
Any idea how to force MySQL to accept this query, or force MSAccess/ODBC to write it up differently ?

Comment: There is a 3rd party app called "MS Access to Mysql" from bullzip.com. have you checked this?

Comment: Yeah I checked, it uses ODBC the same way I do, so the query generated is the same.

Comment: no you haven't.. That app has export to SQL file option where you can export and then run your exception list before importing the SQL!

Comment: I saw it can create a dump file of all the queries generated, that I would have to manually edit for all the databases/queries that would be wrong in the syntax given by the ODBC driver...
That's gonna be a treat.. , and no real automation for future exports possible either :/..

Comment: question is, have you exported as sql and checked if it's exporting as Float or decimal type? Have you tried to change your Access Field type to Decimal and then exported?

Comment: As said in my Question, query generated is the same, so exported as Float(255).
When Access Field type changed to Decimal, it's exported as DECIMAL(18,0) via ODBC, and it works.
I can't really afford to change all the fields into Decimal tho.

Comment: The real question would be why the syntax is the right one when exporting decimal, but not when exporting a float...

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue using "MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver" (5.03.07.00); it does `CREATE TABLE \`mytable\`(\`varField\` varchar(255),\`doubleField\` double)`. If you are using MariaDB Connector/ODBC then perhaps you could try using MySQL Connector/ODBC to see if it works any better. You might also [edit] your question to show the versions of the MariaDB server and connector(s) that you are using.